# socketIO handshake behavior when connecting to different namespaces

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am having troubles with socketIO (nodejs) and using multiple namespaces. Maybe I misunderstood how to use it, but this is how I understood it should work.

Server side (nodejs)

```
io.of('/game').on('connection', socket => {
    console.log(socket.handshake.query);
    console.log('user connected to game socket', socket.id);
})

io.of('/api').on('connection',socket => {
    console.log(socket.handshake.query);
    console.log('user connected to api socket', socket.id);
}
```

Client side (browser)

```
function test (){    
    gameSocketTest = io.connect('http://localhost:4003/game',{query:{test:'test'}});
    apiSocketTest = io.connect('http://localhost:4003/api');       
}
```

The weird thing is that the query (that I only send to the "game" namespace) arrives in both handlers, also the one of the api.

If I inverse the order of the client side code to:

```
function test (){
    apiSocketTest = io.connect('http://localhost:4003/api');        
    gameSocketTest = io.connect('http://localhost:4003/game',{query:{test:'test'}});    
}
```

the query in the handshake is empty in both handlers server side. So my conclusion is that one way or another the same handshake is used for both connections (however the socket ids are different for both).

Is it "uberhaupt" possible to do what I am trying to do? If so, what am I not understanding with this weird handshake behavior.

In my understanding calling on the client side "io.connect()" should create 2 separate socket io clients, each with their own handshake.

Thanks for any help!

Andries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must open new connection explicitly as Socket.IO tries to be smart and re-use connections (which causes a lot of connection issues actually) The way around this is use the force new connection option in your io.connect

```
gameSocketTest = io.connect('http://localhost:4003/game',{query:{test:'test'}});
apiSocketTest = io.connect('http://localhost:4003/api', {'force new connection': true});
```

[From docs](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/)

> When called, it creates a new Manager for the given URL, and attempts
>   to reuse an existing Manager for subsequent calls, unless the
>   multiplex option is passed with false. Passing this option is the equivalent of passing 'force new connection': true